# PHP reporting error. DB verify how to?

Tags: php, mysql, database, validation

Error reporting Notice:

```
Undefined variable: random_chars in wamp\www\php_sandbox\idgen.php on line 21

Call Stack:
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0045  678928  {main}( )   ..\idgen.php:0
GPB7446
```

How do I fix this error?

Using this code like an automatic unique id generator. How do I connect to DB to verify code is truly unique before allowing it to be assigned to a user creating a new account?

Thanks

```
<?php
$characters = array(
"A","B","E","F","G","H","J","K","M","N","P","R","S","T","W","X","Y","Z");
$keys = array();
while(count($keys) < 3) {
$x = mt_rand(0, count($characters)-1);
if(!in_array($x, $keys)) {
$keys[] = $x;
}
}
foreach($keys as $key){
$random_chars .= $characters[$key];}
$randNum = rand(2327,9987); $randLet = rand(2327,9987);
echo $random_chars . $randNum;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the quick answers. I'm just starting to learn this and so far lynda videos and you guys are my saving grace. @basiclife I wish I knew what you were explaining, but i do not. is their a site I can go to that you know of? im using mysql and phpmyadmin, apache.  What i want to do is generate a code for each person who signs up to my site. But before the code is given and recorded in the db for that user, I need the PHP to check my DB and ensure that the code is unique (not already linked to another user) before being assigned. Thanks for the fast replies everyone.

Comment: FYI commenting on the answer is more likely to get attention :) I'll edit my answer with more information

Comment: Have a look now. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare and initialize `$random_chars` before you start concatenating stuff to  it.

Fixed below. I set random_chars to a null string. `$random_chars = "";`

```
$characters = array("A","B","E","F","G","H","J","K","M","N","P","R","S","T","W","X","Y","Z");
$keys = array();
while(count($keys) < 3) {
         $x = mt_rand(0, count($characters)-1);
         if(!in_array($x, $keys)) {
         $keys[] = $x;}
}

$random_chars = ""; //Here

foreach($keys as $key){
      $random_chars .= $characters[$key];
}
$randNum = rand(2327,9987); $randLet = rand(2327,9987);
echo $random_chars . $randNum;
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me what to search for to learn how to cross reference the code generated with a database and only echo the code if it is unique?

Comment: @Mob I take your point, I thought null string only applied to languages which use a null character to terminate the string ala C - Hence empty string is literally `\0`

Answer (score 2):

You're not initialising `$random_chars` - try setting it to an empty string before concatenating it.

```
...
$random_chars="";
foreach($keys as $key){
    $random_chars .= $characters[$key];
}
$randNum = rand(2327,9987); $randLet = rand(2327,9987);
echo $random_chars . $randNum;
...
```

The reason you're getting the error is clearer if you use the long-hand syntax...

```
    $random_chars .= $characters[$key];
```

is the same as

```
    $random_chars = $random_chars . $characters[$key];
```

And the first time that line of code is run, `$random_chars` doesn't exist.

As to checking the database, that depends on the data access mechanism you're using.

You'd need to issue a query similar to:

`SELECT COUNT(*) As RecordCount FROM MyUserTable WHERE MyIdColumn = 'ABC123'`

You'd then read the RecordCount value of the first row of the returned recordset. This should be 0 if it doesn't already exist and >0 if it does.

**Edit: To clarify the database bit...**

The basic process is as follows:

During development:

- Create a database
- Add a table to record these Ids

At Runtime:

- Create a connection to the database
- Send a query asking how many records already have that Id
- Get the response (The "Result Set")
- Examing the result set to see what the server said.

A wordy but detailed intro to PHP and MySQL can be found here:
http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

You should also read up on something called "SQL Injection" which you need to be aware of when developing any website that uses a database and can be seen by anyone other than you.

Some example code is below. You'll need to change the table and column names to match what you used when you created the database. I'm assuming the Db server is the same machine as the web server - if not, change localhost to the appropriate IP/hostname.

```
$user="username";
$password="password";
$database="database";
mysql_connect("localhost",$user,$password); //Connect to server
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database"); //Select your database
$query="SELECT * FROM MyUserTable WHERE MyIdColumn = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($random_chars . $randNum) . "'"; //Define the query
$recordset = mysql_query($query);//Run it
$matchingRecordCount = mysql_numrows($recordset)
mysql_close();//Close the Db connection
if(matchingRecordCount>0) {
    //It's already in there, generate another
} else {
    //It's not already in there
}
```

Just to make sure you're aware, databases are already VERY good and fast at issuing unique Ids (read up on AUTO_INCREMENT) so unless you REALLY want it in this format for some reason, consider just using that.

Comment: Again, Thanks a lot for your help! I will read up on that right now. Thank you.

Comment: Yes I do need it in that format because it will be used like a promotional code. (easy so omitted some chars)  Read up on SQL injection and seems like a serious issue even for some of the biggest tech companies... how do I secure my data? If I lose all of my users info..that's major.

Comment: You should not be using ext/mysql anymore, it is in the process of deprecation, see: http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799 Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: @Maerlyn is absolutely right - but it was a simple example to get you underway. You need something called parameterised queries. Eg when I use a database from a Code Igniter app, Instead of doing `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Blah WHERE A=1")`, I'd do `query("SELECT * FROM Blah WHERE A=?", array(1))`. Note that I'm using a placeholder for the variable (the `?`) and then pass in the actual values seperately. Each data access layer has its own syntax. Start reading at the link Maerlyn gave you...

Comment: @iamfab All that effort answering and you marked Mob's answer as correct. Do you mind if I ask what you thought was lacking from my answer/better in Mob's?

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm reading up on it atm. Geez, it's so much content to get in. I'm trying to launch my startup and make the world a better place. I can't do it all by myself. I'm trying to put together a pre-launch app to get the public involved. My company is about helping people unfortunatly VC's are only willing to fund me if i give them a majority stake. It takes away from the users and I wont allow it. Again thanks for the help. You're helping a great cause. Bless you.

Comment: @iamfab We've all been there - So don't worry, we understand. If you haven't had a VC pull out at the last minute, you haven't tried enough startups :) If you don't mind, I'd still appreciate an answer to my question to allow me to improve my answers in future. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize `$random_chars` to an empty string before the loop:

```
$random_chars = "";
foreach($keys as $key) {
  $random_chars .= $characters[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just declare `$random_chars = "";` above `foreach($keys as $key)` and that should fix it